# AudioManager.setStreamSolo() broken in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android

Has anyone run into stream soloing not working properly in Jelly Bean?

This used to work fine in all Android versions up to and including ICS:

```
audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);   
...
audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

That succesfully soloed the system stream that I use for my app's alerts and silenced the music stream if the user was playing something. And then unsoloed back to normal.
But now on Jelly Bean the soloing also mutes the system stream itself!

Here's a debug log from an Android 2.3 emulator with all the stream volumes after soloing and unsoloing:

```
07-20 09:02:45.948: E/solo(331): Alarm: 6
07-20 09:02:45.988: E/solo(331): Dtmf: 12
07-20 09:02:45.988: E/solo(331): Music: 0
07-20 09:02:45.988: E/solo(331): Notification: 0
07-20 09:02:45.988: E/solo(331): Ring: 0
07-20 09:02:45.988: E/solo(331): System: 7
07-20 09:02:46.000: E/solo(331): Call: 4

07-20 09:02:50.248: E/unsolo(331): Alarm: 6
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): Dtmf: 12
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): Music: 11
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): Notification: 5
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): Ring: 5
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): System: 7
07-20 09:02:50.258: E/unsolo(331): Call: 4
```

So all's fine, the system stream stays on, music goes down.
Here's Android 4.1:

```
07-20 09:06:15.483: E/solo(1623): Alarm: 6
07-20 09:06:15.483: E/solo(1623): Dtmf: 0
07-20 09:06:15.493: E/solo(1623): Music: 0
07-20 09:06:15.493: E/solo(1623): Notification: 0 
07-20 09:06:15.493: E/solo(1623): Ring: 0
07-20 09:06:15.524: E/solo(1623): System: 0
07-20 09:06:15.544: E/solo(1623): Call: 4

07-20 09:06:19.775: E/unsolo(1623): Alarm: 6
07-20 09:06:19.784: E/unsolo(1623): Dtmf: 15
07-20 09:06:19.794: E/unsolo(1623): Music: 13
07-20 09:06:19.794: E/unsolo(1623): Notification: 7
07-20 09:06:19.803: E/unsolo(1623): Ring: 7
07-20 09:06:19.803: E/unsolo(1623): System: 7
07-20 09:06:19.803: E/unsolo(1623): Call: 4
```

Jelly Bean mutes more streams, including the system stream that was supposed to solo.

Comment: Also added this to the oh so useful Android bug database where it will undoubtedly be lost forever: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35378